# Duda en campo a super clase

Tags: swift, herencia, diseño-de-clases

Hola chicos pues estoy con la siguiente duda en una subclase por herencia usando `self`.

Supongamos la clase deporte y futbol

```swift
class Deporte{
  var numeroJugadores: Int
  //propiedades extra
}

class Futbol: Deporte{
  var nombre: String
  
  func imprimeNumeroJugadores() {
    print(self.numeroJugadores)
    // ó
    print(numeroJugadores)
  }
}
```

Mi duda es cúal debe ser la forma correcta de acceder a la propiedad de la super clase? con o sin el `self`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no declaras los inicializadores en cada clase te marca un error de compilación. Para acceder a las propiedades de las super clase utilizas `super`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
class Deporte{
  var numeroJugadores: Int = 11 //Inicializador para evitar error de compilación
  //propiedades extra
}

class Futbol: Deporte{
  var nombre: String = "Fútbol"//Inicializador para evitar error de compilación
  
  func imprimeNumeroJugadores() {
    print(super.numeroJugadores)//Acceso a los miembros de la super clase
    print(self.nombre)//Acceso a los miembros de la clase
  }
}

let futbol = Futbol()
futbol.imprimeNumeroJugadores()//Imprime "11" y "Fútbol
```

Al momento de escribir `super.` puedes ver que solo te aparecen las propiedades de la super clase mientras que con `self.`, accedes a la super clase `Deporte` y a la clase `Futbol`, esto por la herencia. Incluso puedes acceder sin ningún prefijo pero una buena práctica sería diferenciar los prefijos de acceso:

**Super clase**

```
super
```

**Clases**

```
self
```

Comment: Ok entonces me dices que la forma correcta sería con `super`?

Comment: Se entendería mejor el código.